# jQuery tab and content outside the current webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bit of a silly question here but here goes... say I wish to use the jQuery tabs but instead of my tabs pointing to DIVs within the same page I want to point them to pages within my site or even external pages... for example

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="content/page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="content/page4.html">Page 4</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="profile">
        <p>Profile</p>
    </div>
    <div id="photos">
        <p>Photos</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the tabs pointing to Page 3 and Page 4 would I have to use an IFrame or a Div with an iFrame within to display the desired content? For example

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="content/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="profile">
            <p>Profile</p>
        </div>
        <div id="photos">
            <p>Photos</p>
        </div>

         <div id="page3">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>

or 

 <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="content/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="profile">
    <p>Profile</p>
</div>
<div id="photos">
    <p>Photos</p>
</div>

     <iframe id="page3"></iframe>
```

If this question makes no sense or my wording is bad please say and I'll improve my question.

UPDATE **

Sorry I should add that when using the original code (the first block) the tabs that reference pages and not DIVs are not shown when the user uses IE8. IE9 seems fine... my problem was risen when testing in IE8! However the first tab (pointing to Page1) is displayed when the page loads... when I click on the Page 3 or Page 4 links nothing is shown...

Comment: Do you want to load the full page? or simply content that's in another page? Would this demo do what you need? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: I want to load content that's in another page, I'll check out the demo... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQueryUI Tabs`, you could use `select` or `show` event for this. For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    show: function(event, ui) {
        // do your stuff with changing attribute `src` of your iframe
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use an iFrame: `<iframe id="page3"></iframe>`

Have you tried this and run into some kind of problem?

Comment: Sorry I should add that when using the original code the tabs are not shown when the user uses IE8. IE9 seems fine... my problem was risen when testing in IE8!

Comment: Does the page validate?
If you open up the IE dev tools (I'm assuming you're using 9) and force it to display in IE8 - Standards, does it work?